# Alphabetical list selector like iOS with HTML5 and jQuery Swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a list with a listbar like a iOS, but I can'nt. I created an alphabetical list, ie:

```
<div class="content">
   <ul class="alphabetical-list">
       <li class="a"></li>
       <li class="b"></li>
       <li class="c"></li>
       ...
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="linkbar">
  <ul class="alphabetical">
     <li>A</li>
     <li>B</li>
     <li>C</li>
     <li>...</li>
     <li>X</li>
     <li>Y</li>
     <li>Z</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have one header in position absolute, with 100px height. And I'm trying to control as follow:

```
var anima = 0;
var old = 0;
function animate(touchHeight){
    old = anima;
    if(touchHeight > 105 && touchHeight < 130) {
        anima = $(".a").offset().top-100;
    }
    if(touchHeight > 130 && touchHeight < 155) {
        anima = $(".b").offset().top-100;
    }
    if(touchHeight > 155 && touchHeight < 180) {
        anima = $(".c").offset().top-100;
    }
    ...
    if(touchHeight > 650 && touchHeight < 675) {
        anima = $(".x").offset().top-100;
    }
    if(touchHeight > 675 && touchHeight < 700) {
        anima = $(".y").offset().top-100;
    }
    if(touchHeight > 700 && touchHeight < 725) {
        anima = $(".z").offset().top-100;
    }
    anima = anima + old;    
    $('.content').animate({scrollTop: anima},500);
}

$(".alphabetical").touchmove(function(e){
    touchHeight = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;;
    animate(touchHeight);
});
```

But it is not working, because the contents of the list comes from a JSON.

Even starting function after the content is loaded, the script seems to fumble when I try to instantiate the animation by swiping the screen.

Comment: Define "not working". What should happen, what should it look like? What is happening instead?

Comment: When the user touches the bar, the contents should be placed in the selected letter. Like an anchor. But if I swipe the bar, the selector must follow according to the letter of the selected alphabet. As in the alphabet bar in native iOS Contacts list. So didn't work, when I swipe the alhabetic bar, rather than going for the selected letter, the contents go to different points.